# Compiling Programs in OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I'm just starting with OpenCV and am stuck running the sample code on [this website](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/display_image/display_image.html#display-image).

I made a `.cpp` file and copy/pasted the code in.

I ran the following command on the command line:

> g++ program.cpp -o program

I got the following errors:

> undefined reference to `cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)'
>
> program.cpp:(.text+0x128): undefined reference to
>   `cv::namedWindow(cv::String const&, int)'
>
> program.cpp:(.text+0x17d): undefined reference to
>   `cv::imshow(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&)'
>
> program.cpp:(.text+0x1a5): undefined reference to `cv::waitKey(int)'
>
> /tmp/cceJEar6.o: In function `cv::String::String(char const*)':
>
> program.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringC2EPKc[_ZN2cv6StringC5EPKc]+0x4d):
>   undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned long)'

It seems to be a linking problem where it can't find the cv namespace or the opencv libraries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't specified the OpenCV libraries while compiling.
Use this command:

```
g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv` codename.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv` -o codename
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the library files as linker flags.

> g++ program.cpp -o program -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui

For this specific program, only the **core** and **highgui** modules of OpenCV are required. The list will increase as functionality from other modules are added in the program.

Answer (score 0):

```
g++ -ggdb `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o outResize *.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

then compile

`./run`